# SQLAlchemy EXISTS queryset

Tags: django, orm, sqlalchemy, exists

I use only django framework with his ORM.

And there is some code:

```
User.objects.filter(username='test').exists()
```

that return True or False.

this orm query generate SQL:

```
SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."username" = E'test'  LIMIT 1
```

How I can perform equal query in SQLAlchemy?

I try understand this page
http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html#using-exists
but can't understand how this works.

Help please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

(ret,), = Session.query(exists().where(User.username=='test'))

Comment: You can use `sqlalchemy.orm.Query.scalar()` instead of that (admittedly clever) `(result,), = etc` unpacking.